# HOW TO RESET ROW NUMBER?

Tags: netezza

[table master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjsu3.jpg)

How To sort row_num based on date interval 1 day?

to make the output like this with netezza:

[after sort and reset row num table master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMdZ4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is *difficult* to do if you are just relying on set based logic and windows functions (row number, etc) as you need to be continually looking at the next row to establish if the date is within 1 day of current.

Gut feeling is that you will need either a cursor or while loop logic.

One "quick" solution is to run a pre-parse script on your data that derives a "matching group" value.

Once you have the matching group value you can easily use your windows functions.

Something like this (there are most likely other/better ways of deriving the match group).

I've also added a RowId INT as a **primary key** so that you can easily self join using + or - logic (forwards/backwards).

Basically, loop over data adding a match group INT when the next date is between 0 and 1 day of current.

```
DECLARE
    @TestData TABLE
    (
        [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        [Date] DATETIME,
        RowId INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
        MatchGroupKey INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData
(
    Id,
    [Date]
)
VALUES
(
    NEWID(), '20190504'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190513'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190515'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190516'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190517'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190521'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190522'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190523'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190524'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190526'
),
(
    NEWID(), '20190527'
);

-- Derive a "match group" key

DECLARE
    @LoopCounter INT = 1,
    @TotalRows INT =
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            @TestData
    );

DECLARE
    @CurrentID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @CurrentDate DATETIME,
    @CurrentRowId INT,
    @NextID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @NextDate DATETIME,
    @NextRowId INT,
    @MatchGroupKey INT = 1;

WHILE (@LoopCounter <= @TotalRows)
BEGIN

    -- Get current row
    SELECT
        @CurrentID = Id,
        @CurrentDate = [Date],
        @CurrentRowId = RowId
    FROM
        @TestData
    WHERE
        RowId = @LoopCounter;

    --Get next row
    SELECT
        @NextID = Id,
        @NextDate = [Date],
        @NextRowId = RowId
    FROM
        @TestData
    WHERE
        RowId = @LoopCounter + 1;

    IF DATEDIFF(dd, @CurrentDate, @NextDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 1
    BEGIN

        --If next row is same or within 1 day then update current/previous with match group

        UPDATE
            t1
        SET
            t1.MatchGroupKey = @MatchGroupKey
        FROM
            @TestData t1
        WHERE
            t1.RowId IN (@LoopCounter, @LoopCounter + 1);

    END; ELSE BEGIN

        --If next row is not within the 1 day then update just the current row with match value and increment the match value for next iteration
        UPDATE
            t1
        SET
            t1.MatchGroupKey = @MatchGroupKey
        FROM
            @TestData t1
        WHERE
            t1.RowId IN (@LoopCounter);

        SET @MatchGroupKey += 1;

    END;

    SET @LoopCounter += 1;

END;
```

### Result

```
3FEADF3A-8380-46C6-8280-314FD2F619FB    2019-05-04 00:00:00.000 1   1
C487A5B9-285C-4C4F-A2BD-D1AD6272BEC2    2019-05-13 00:00:00.000 2   2
273E41FD-B910-42AB-BF22-ECE9B13B2EDA    2019-05-15 00:00:00.000 3   3
4C5E8A74-8B2E-41D8-9F32-012EBB030631    2019-05-16 00:00:00.000 4   3
1794C36E-CAA1-430C-9BB2-CECC1A85BBCE    2019-05-17 00:00:00.000 5   3
853B8296-5040-44CF-8F1C-F3E9CF5ADC24    2019-05-21 00:00:00.000 6   4
7E7E4288-13CC-4060-BCFF-A75FB4554B1D    2019-05-22 00:00:00.000 7   4
745BEE56-C2CC-4FC8-939F-DB1F5C713015    2019-05-23 00:00:00.000 8   4
F25613A6-B7CF-4131-A697-CC3A974595FC    2019-05-24 00:00:00.000 9   4
F98A02AD-8570-4A7D-B752-A34648949498    2019-05-26 00:00:00.000 10  5
D582E2BB-7625-4E12-8A09-90D1C2E769EC    2019-05-27 00:00:00.000 11  5
```

So now you have a match group value in last column.

Now it's easy to get your result:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    [Date],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MatchGroupKey ORDER BY Date) rn
FROM
    @TestData;
```

### Result

```
5204D618-B0D9-4186-AD18-7A7C4D4220B2    2019-05-04 00:00:00.000 1
F263AAAD-1CC3-4BDE-8E16-4DE890D0012B    2019-05-13 00:00:00.000 1
8FAD9002-3951-4E63-B012-C3C9E87D7700    2019-05-15 00:00:00.000 1
26CB938B-638D-40F4-B18D-6225EBF6F739    2019-05-16 00:00:00.000 2
472646E4-FD36-43E0-B579-F542AFA7110B    2019-05-17 00:00:00.000 3
7EB4248D-B942-423B-A756-FF9438CD80DF    2019-05-21 00:00:00.000 1
103027EC-5D5E-4BD9-99A8-44274F0BE383    2019-05-22 00:00:00.000 2
79609995-D2CE-443E-AE17-DE3D9B4B6F40    2019-05-23 00:00:00.000 3
273ADCD6-0CC8-4DB9-9627-CC6FAA87D388    2019-05-24 00:00:00.000 4
3D6E53F0-976F-4FFC-936B-9503E28DE862    2019-05-26 00:00:00.000 1
573ED4AC-F370-48E5-BE79-65A847AD6CA4    2019-05-27 00:00:00.000 2
```